# How to stop executing data aquisition and display method in event handler

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

This is the first time to ask a question here and not an English native.
So if my question is ambiguous, I'm sorry about that.

[Development environment: Windows10, Visual Studio 2017, .net framework 4.7.2]

I'm working on a windows form app.
What is the best practice to implement following function.

On User Interface, there are 4 comboboxes
`cmbGradeFrom`: select the range of grade from 
`cmbGradeTo`: select the range of grade to
`cmbClassFrom`: select the range of class from
`cmbClassTo`: select the range of class to

Once each combobox are changed, each eventhandler executes,
and in the method, `setEachFeeList()`, there is a sql query,
in which the target data to obtain is narrowed down from `cmbGradeFrom` to `cmbGradeTo`
and from `cmbClassFrom` to `cmbClassTo`. And display the data on the data grid view.

As the code tells, if you change the choice of one combobox,
it affects another combobox's value.
So Just changing the value of combobox one time sometimes leads to
execute `setEachFeeList()` method.

I want to make it as if I change one combobox value, other three combobox value change,
and execute `setEachFeeList()` method only once.
Is there any way to implement this function?

I have tried using bool vairiable to check whether accessing data is needed.
I have tried removing or adding eventhandler to control whether accessing data is needed.

```cs
/// when cmbGradeFrom changed
protected void cmbGradeFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbGradeFrom.Items.Count == 0 || cmbGradeTo.Items.Count == 0) return;

    if (cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex > cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex) 
    {
        cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex = cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex;
    }

    /// when cmbGradeFrom and cmbGradeTo are the same, set default cmbClassFrom and cmbClassTo
    if (cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex == cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex)
    {
        setClassFromTo();
    }
    else
    {
        //get data using sql and display
        setEachFeeList(); 
    }
}

/// when cmbGradeTo changed
protected void cmbGradeTo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbGradeFrom.Items.Count == 0 || cmbGradeTo.Items.Count == 0) 
    return;

    if (cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex > cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex)
    {
        cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex = cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex;
    }

    /// when cmbGradeFrom and cmbGradeTo are the same, set default cmbClassFrom and cmbClassTo
    if (cmbGradeFrom.SelectedIndex == cmbGradeTo.SelectedIndex)
        setClassFromTo(); 
    }
    else
    {
        //get data using sql and display
        setEachFeeList(); 
    }
}
/// when cmbClassFrom changed
protected void cmbClassFrom_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbClassFrom.Items.Count == 0 || cmbClassTo.Items.Count == 0) return;

    if (cmbClassFrom.SelectedIndex > cmbClassTo.SelectedIndex) 
    {
        cmbClassTo.SelectedIndex = cmbClassFrom.SelectedIndex;
    }
    //get data using sql and display
    setEachFeeList();
}
/// when cmbClassTo changed
protected void cmbClassTo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbClassFrom.Items.Count == 0 || cmbClassTo.Items.Count == 0) return;

    if (cmbClassFrom.SelectedIndex > cmbClassTo.SelectedIndex) 
    {
        cmbClassFrom.SelectedIndex = cmbClassTo.SelectedIndex;
    }
    //get data using sql and display
    setEachFeeList();
}
```

Comment: why are you using TextChanged event and not using selectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: @sharmav1 if I change it to selectedIndexChanged, it will work as I asked? Anyway, I try it. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @sharmav1 Thank you for your advice, I did not change it to selectedIndexChanged but instead I changed it to DropDownClosed.